# React / Strapi - API request put data in the CMS

Tags: reactjs, fetch, gatsby, strapi

Quick question: I made a API fetch function for my Strapi CMS but can't seem to get the right JSON.
This results in my API call adding a new item within the Strapi CMS (200 OK HTTP). But without the provided data. I'm guessing that the JSON is wrongly formatted and the data gets lost.

**What works:**

- Authorization works
- API request works (200)
- There is an empty article within the Strapi CMS

**What doesn't work:**

- Data doesn't get set within the CMS.
  The code:

```js
  // POST request using fetch with error handling
  function setArticle() {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${state.jwt}` 
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        slug: "first-success",
        name: "First successful API request"
      })
    
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:1337/articles', requestOptions)
      .then(async response => {
        const data = await response.json();

        console.log(requestOptions);
        // check for error response
        if (!response.ok) {
            // get error message from body or default to response status
            const error = (data && data.message) || response.status;
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        this.setState({ postId: data.id })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was an error!');
    });

  }
```

What I tried, logging and reading the Strapi documentation.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was, **case sensitivity**. Apparently when making a new content type within Strapi I set the entity with an uppercase. (**S**lug and **N**ame) resulting to my `body` within my HTTP request getting ignore.

I changed the Strapi fields without an uppercase and it's now working.

```
  body: JSON.stringify({
    slug: "first-success",
    name: "First successful API request"
  })
```